# R: Reading from an existing connection in compiled code

Tags: r, api, connection

I'd like to be able to read from an arbitrary R connection (in the sense of `?connections`), which would be passed to an R function by the user and then down into some C code via `.Call`.

The R API, in file `R_ext/Connections.h`, specifies a function, `R_ReadConnection`, which takes a pointer to an `Rconn` struct as its first argument, and does what I want. The struct itself is also defined in that header, but I see no way of retrieving a struct of that type, aside from `getConnection` (the C function), which is not part of the API. As far as I can tell, the external pointer associated with the connection also does not point to the struct directly.

So, could anyone please tell me whether there is a supported way to convert a suitable `SEXP` to a pointer to the associated `Rconn` struct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R API function `R_GetConnection()` was added in R 3.3.0. It performs the conversion from `SEXP` to pointer to `Rconn` (a.k.a. `Rconnection`). Hence, the solution is now

```
#include <R_ext/Connections.h>

SEXP myfunction (SEXP conn_)
{
    Rconnection conn = R_GetConnection(conn_);
    // Do something with the connection
    
    return R_NilValue;
}
```

This was [documented in `NEWS`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/NEWS.3):

> R_GetConnection() which allows packages implementing connections
> to convert R connection objects to Rconnection handles. Code
> which previously used the low-level R-internal getConnection()
> entry point should switch.

Comment: What's the correct way to call this from R?  Would it be `.Call("myfunction", textConnection(LETTERS))?`

Comment: Sadly this ability to access connections via C seems to have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is (this is an oversight, I think). The workaround is to declare an appropriate prototype and use it

```
Rconnection getConnection(int n);

SEXP connect_me(SEXP conn) {
    getConnection(INTEGER(conn)[0]);
    return R_NilValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works functionally, but R complains about non-API calls so I guess this route is out for a published package